# Two different results for same JS,when ran through Browser's JS Console and through a JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Punches</a>
        <div class="def">
            <h2>Punches</h2>
            <ul id="PARENT" class="PARENT">
                <li class="CHILD"><a href="#item1">This Is Sparta</a></li>
                <li class="CHILD"><a href="#item2">You Shall not pass</a></li>
                <li class="CHILD"><a href="#item3">May the force be with you</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Whistles</a>
        <div class="def">
            <h2>Whistles</h2>
            <ul id="PARENT" class="PARENT">
                <li  class="CHILD"><a href="#item4">How you doin ?</a></li>
                <li  class="CHILD"><a href="#item5">Let's put another shrimp on the barbequeue</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>           
</ul>
```

When I type $('ul.PARENT > li.CHILD'); in browser's JS Console I am getting array of length 5, but when I do the exact same thing from a file, I get the array length as 3. i.e When I click link named "How you doin ?", it shows object at index 0 is selected instead of showing object at index 3 has been selected. Can anyone tell me how is this happening ?

Comment: `id="PARENT"` twice, IDs have to be unique

Comment: ID always unique so you can not have elements with same id.
PARENT and CHILD ID

Comment: Sorry, thats a mistake, but correcting it doesn't effect the result. I am still having the same problem.

Comment: try this $('ul.PARENT > li');

Comment: tried it still same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found the problem with the count.

But the index() method acts differently based on how it is called.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $lis = $('ul.PARENT > li.CHILD');
    console.log($lis.length);
    $lis.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($lis.index(this))
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dvWM6/)

If you want the overall index of the current element against a set of elements, then use the above syntax

Comment: I edited my code as per your suggestion and it works great. It was the index() method acting differently. Thanx a million. :)